# Confusion about validity of integration by substitution method

Tags: integration, derivatives, continuity

Suppose $$ f(x,y) = \int g(x,y,t)\, dt, $$ and I wish to do the integral over $ t $ by setting $$ t = h(x,y,\tau). $$ As an example, suppose $$ h(x,y,\tau) = \frac{\tau}{\cos x} -\tan y. $$ If we choose nice values for $ x $ and $ y $, say $ x = y = \pi/4 $, then everything is fine as $ h(x,y,\tau) $ is continuously differentiable.

However, is the substitution still valid if $ x\in [0, \pi] $ and $ y \in [0, 2\pi] $? Do we have to care about the behaviour of the components that are not explicitly a function of $ t $ or  $ \tau $?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get the notation used for the integral here? "dt" goes after the function, not before it. This looks like it could be massively confusing with multiple integrals.

Comment: Thanks. I'll change it. It's common in the field that I work.

Comment: If an integrand is not continuous, then the integral may or may not exist. In particular, if you make a substitution that turns the integrand into a noncontinuous function (perhaps because it's not defined at certain places), then you are opening the door to trouble - improper integrals, at the very least, which may or may not converge.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Greg. My concern is not with the resulting integrand being difficult to work with, but rather with the validity of the change of variable. I am inclined to label the substitution given above as invalid, but I am not absolutely certain.Furthermore, if it helps, you can assume the integral is definite or improper.